# The use of the word "void" in Romans 3:31?

Tags: grammar

This seems to be a question that only lawyers could answer but why would footnotes pertaining to the words "make void" in this passage of Romans be understood as nullify?

---

> [Romans 3:31, King James Bible "Authorized Version", Cambridge Edition](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Romans-3-31/)
>    *Do we then **make void** the law through faith? God forbid: yea, we establish the law.*

Comment: Could you actually quote the verse so we don't have to look it up ourselves?

Comment: It would also be good to indicate which Bible version/translation you are using.

Comment: I've flagged this as belonging better on Hermeneutics.SE.

Comment: Ever heard of "null and void"?

Answer (score 5):

Void can be used as an adjective or a verb meaning "to nullify".

[Definition per Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=void%20definition&oq=void%20definition):

> **adjective**
>
> 1. not valid or legally binding. "the contract was void"
>    **synonyms:** invalid, null, ineffective, nonviable, useless, worthless,
>    nugatory *"the election was void"*
>
> **verb**
>
> 1. NORTH AMERICAN declare that (something) is not valid or legally binding. *"the Supreme Court voided
>    the statute"*
>    **synonyms:**
>    invalidate, annul, nullify; negate, quash, cancel, countermand, repeal, revoke, rescind, retract, withdraw, reverse, undo, abolish; vacate; formalabrogate "the contract was voided"

Comment: Indeed, and in the passage in question it is this adjective sense here, along with the verb *make*. Some other translations use *nullify* where the KJV uses *make void*

Comment: @James I don't understand your question (and presumably your downvote). "Make void" is a phrase, the individual parts would have meaning. I think by understanding that "void" means to "nullify" more than adequately answers the original question.

Comment: I guess my point is that 'make void' is a well-known verbal phrase and it has a long-standing [definition](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/make+void) meaning annul or cancel, which are both verbs.  Since you've corrected the part-of-speech issue I remove my downvote.

Comment: @James Yeah, I was utterly confused by your statement, but it did point out to me that I mistyped adverb. Apparently that was your point all along. :)

Answer (score 3):

*Make void* was the 1611 English translation of the Latin term *destruimus* (Void or undo) http://glosbe.com/la/en/destruimus which was a translation of the Greek *katargoumen* (make void) http://biblemaster.com/bible/view.asp?number=2673 Some modern translations render the word *nullify*.

Full Definition of NULLIFY
transitive verb
1:  to make null; especially:  to make legally null and void 
2:  to make of no value or consequence

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nullify

Answer (score 2):

The word being translated is καταργοῦμεν, “[we] *make of no effect”* ([LSJ s.v. καταργέω, citing this verse](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3atext:1999.04.0057%3aentry=katarge/w)).

I believe that per its own advertisement in the Epistle Dedicatory the KJV translates direct from the “Original Sacred Tongues”—not via Latin.

Comment: The 'Original Sacred Tongues' doesn't make sense. The original Scriptures were inspired and inerrant, not the languages employed. Many people still believe that the KJV is the version we 'should' use because it was 'authorised'. Better and more accessible modern translations are thankfully available today.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, “thankfully” does not meaningfully modify “available”

Comment: @jwpat7 I'm glad you've realised that, or I would have wondered if commas were necessary to identify the pragmatic marker usage (speaker comment expressing attitude): **MW: thankfully** 2: as makes one thankful –  _graceless stadiums ... thankfully going out of fashion_ . Below, I've given an overview of the different usages, as adverbs and evaluative pragmatic markers (traditionally but incongruously called 'evaluative [sentence] adverbs), and how to avoid the possible ambiguity.

Comment: @jwpat7 Evaluative adverbs express the speaker's evaluation of an associated statement. This may be agent- (eg wisely) or event- (or content-) (eg regrettably) orientated. They may be used as ordinary adverbs and secondary modifiers, so care needs to be exercised when a medial position is chosen: Happily, they were playing in the garden when the man delivered their Christmas present. // They were playing happily in the garden when the man delivered their Christmas present. /// Happily, they were married. = They were, happily, married. =/= They were happily married.